# Facebook Like Feed Notification

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I need to get 'like log' in Facebook.

As you know, ActivityLog was launched recently. (http://www.facebook.com/help/activitylog)
The ActivityLog is a list of your posts and activity including 'likes'.

That is what I want.
Specifically, I need post-id you liked and like-timestamp.

But as I known, there isn't any graph api to get like feed (including timestamp).

Thanks in advance.